# Understanding a statement in a paragraph in Royden (4^th edition) on pg.136

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

The paragraph is given below:

> [image]

My question is:
Why this statement "Since complements of sets of measure zero are dense in $\mathbb{R}$" is correct? could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E$ a set of measure zero.

Then assume that $E^c$ is not dense on the real line.

Then exists $(a,b)\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ such that $(a,b)\cap E^c=\emptyset$

Thus $(a,b) \subseteq (E^c)^c=E%$ so $0=m(E) \geq m((a,b))=b-a>0$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a set of measure zero. Assume that $\mathbb R \backslash A$ is not dense. Then, there exists some interval $(a,b)$ such that $(\mathbb R \backslash A) \cap (a,b) =\emptyset$.

But this implies 
$$(a,b) \subset A$$ and hence $A$ has measure at least $b-a$.